# How can I get the RSS-feed to post from YouTube into a chatroom?

Tags: support, chat, feed

[Timothy Gowers YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/TimothyGowers0) is releasing weekly lectures which I'm trying to get the RSS-feed to post into my [chatroom here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105903/room-to-practice-social-distancing). I've tried to post from his channel and from the playlist, neither work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use the channel feed

A link to the channel feed is in the source code for the channel page even though it doesn't appear on the website. It has the form

```
http://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=<channel id>
```

where the `<channel id>` is a base 64 id (the human readable channel name does not work as far as I can tell). I added that feed to your chatroom (as a test) and it posted a backlog of five videos (which is normal behavior). It even one-boxes!